# Passing a value with whitespace from an html page to a view

Tags: django

I'm populating a dropdown box with values from a model as follows (abbreviated):

```
<select name="dropdown">
    {% for thing in storedvalues %}
        <option value={{ thing.name }}>{{ thing.name }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
    <input type="submit" value="Filter" id="bbutton"/>
```

and in the view...

```
def testpage(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        result = request.POST.get('dropdown')
        print("hey this is the value: ", result)
        selected_result = Song.objects.filter(name=result)

        return render(request, 'testpage.html', {'selected_result': selected_result,})
```

This mostly works correctly. I select a value from a dropdown list and it returns the all of the data relating to the selected value. However when a value has white space in it, any characters following the white space are lost. I'm not sure how to go about fixing this.

If anyone could point me in the right direction it would be much appreciated

Comment: I'd start by putting doublequotes around the value. `value="{{thing.name}}"`

Comment: That worked like a charm. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put double quotes around the value otherwise the browser is going to interpret the field as set to empty as such: (yes, I'm using " thing.name" as the value for thing.name - not confusing at all)

`<option value="" thing.name=""> thing.name</option>`

With the quotes it'll be interpreted as:

`<option value=" thing.name"> thing.name</option>`

So just add a couple doublequotes and you'll be golden.

`<option value="{{thing.name}}">{{ thing.name }}</option>`